# SSIS: I don't see the package configuration wizard

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

Using SQLServer 2012 Enterprise, I don't see "Package Configuration Wizard" in SSIS when I do a right click in Control Flow tab. I can see all the other items (Log, Digital Signing...).

Here are info about my install:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel
Professional

SQL Server Analysis Services   
Concepteur Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services 
Version 11.0.2100.60

SQL Server Integration Services   
Concepteur Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services
Version 11.0.2100.60

SQL Server Reporting Services   
Concepteurs Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services
Version 11.0.2100.60
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The 2012 release of SSIS introduces a new model for configuration and deployment called the Project deployment model. As part of that change, the old way of doing configuration (environment, xml, parent package, registry and table) is not an option. In the project deployment model, you get parameters and environments. Thus far, I think it's going to be an improvement.

Fear not though, the classic way of doing things is still available. Right click on your project and select `Convert to Package Deployment Model`

[image]

Comment: Is there a link to the new way of doing things?

Comment: Anything in particular you are looking for @PeterX

Comment: All good - @Joost's answer below has helped - choosing `Configurations` via the Properties pane.

Comment: @billinkc you might wish to update this answer to reflect that package-level config files are in fact still available, even in the Project Deployment Model (as per Joost's answer).  You just have to find the hidden place to go to turn them on.

Answer (score 48):

It is still available, but hidden because [configuring](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.nl/) a package is a little different in the 2012 Project Deployment Model. But if you open a package, right-click in the Control Flow tab, click on the Properties of the package, then you will find a Configurations property under Misc.
[image: Old package configurations]

Comment: Wow.  Pretty sure I would have never found this on my own.

Comment: Wow! Microsoft does it again! They are so good at obfuscating the obvious and changing things around.

Answer (score 2):

1. On the Project Menu, click Convert to Package Deployment Model.
2. Click OK on the warning prompt and, once the conversion is complete, click OK on the Convert to Package Deployment Model dialog.
3. Click the background of the Control Flow tab in SSIS Designer.
4. On the SSIS menu, click Package Configurations.
5. In the Package Configurations Organizer dialog box, select Enable Package Configurations, and then click Add.

See this link >> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms166598.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for providing below information (I was lost how to find this option):

It is still available, but hidden because configuring a package is a little different in the 2012 Project Deployment Model. But if you open a package, right-click in the Control Flow tab, click on the Properties of the package, then you will find a Configurations property under Misc.

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you ran the option "covert to deployment model" and still do not see the "package configuration" option under Menu-> SSIS then you need to follow steps below

1. right click project and click on "properties"
2. you would see two side pane, left side pane select option "Deployment" then right side you would see option "Create deployment utility"
   and set this option to TRUE
3. Click on OK and go back to the package, you would see "Package configuration" would be available
4. shortcut to "package configuration" is right click on empty space within package control flow and select from menu.